# media query in bootstrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I wanted to set image width to `350px` if the desktop size is greater than 1200px in `bootstrap`.

I can do it, if desktop size it greater than 992px. But I can't do it when it is < 1200px.

I tried it something like this but its not working for me.

```
    @media (max-width: (@screen-lg - 1) and (max-width: (@screen-lg))) {
        > img {
            width: 350px;
        }
    }
```

`NOTE:` I need to set this width to my image when the screen size is greater than 992. (Including about 1200px)

Can anybody help me regarding this?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Yes I tried and got it to work...

This is Code :

```
    @media (min-width: (@screen-md)) {
        > img {
            width: 400px;
        }
    }
```